# What's Yii's equivalent for Libraries and Helpers in other PHP frameworks?

Tags: php, yii, helper

What's Yii's way of implementing modular functionality to use from Controllers, as there are Helpers and Libraries on Kohana and CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for 3rd party "added" modular functionality you are looking for Yii's "Extensions".

An extension is a modular piece of code that could be anything: a widget, behavior, etc. They are for Controllers, Models, again: anything. Yii has many chunks of modular functionality built in, for instance Yii's Form widgets are like Cake's form "Helpers". But if you are looking for something not in the Framework already check out Extensions.

[Explanation of Extensions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/extension.overview)

[Yii Extension Library/Repository](http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/)